# .htaccess redirect a url to PHP using RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to setup .htaccess so I can redirect a url like `http://example.com/io/abc123` to `http://example.com/io/io.php?id=abc123`.
But, for some reason, the RewriteRule does not work as I expect.

I want to keep this redirection local without messing up the root .htaccess file, and so I create a new .htaccess file inside the io subdirectory. (Doing the equivalent in the root directory gives the same outcome, so it's not that).

### Directory structure:

```
www
 |
 +--io
    |
    +-- .htaccess
    \-- io.php
```

### .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ io.php?id=$1
```

### io.php file:

```
<?php
  echo "Hello World" . "\n";
  echo "REQUEST_URI=[" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "]\n";
  echo "PHP_SELF=[" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "]\n";
  echo "QUERY_STRING=[" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . "]\n";
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  echo "id='" . $id . "'\n";
  ?>
```

### OUTPUT

```
Hello World
REQUEST_URI=[/io/abc123]
PHP_SELF=[/io/io.php]
QUERY_STRING=[id=io.php]
id='io.php'
```

For reasons I don't understand, instead of the expected query_string `id=abc123` this results in `id=io.php`.

It's obviously getting the rewrite correct to the target file `io.php`, but fails to substitute the `abc123` into the id parameter using $1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For reasons I don't understand, instead of the expected query_string id=abc123 this results in id=io.php

Reason is that your rule is **executing twice** since there is no pre-condition to not to rewrite for existing files and directories.

1. First time it matches `abc123` and rewrites to `io.php?id=abc123`
2. Now our `REQUEST_URI` has become `io.php`. `mod_rewrite` runs in a loop unless there is no executing rule or else if source and target URIs are same.  So second time it matches `io.php` (since our pattern is `.*`) and it gets rewritten to `io.php?id=io.php`.

`mod_rewrite` engine stops here because source and target URIs are same.

To fix this issue, you should use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ io.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```